# Laravel server hosting error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I had built my website using Laravel 4, and it works fine on localhost but when I host it in my online webserver I've got this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/.../public_html/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 3242
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Ok have you had a look at that file where it indicates there's an error?

Comment: yes of course I found this line of code : use MacroableTrait;

Comment: what version of php do u have running on the server ?

Comment: I have PHP Version 5.3.24 :( . Is there any solution to use laravel 4 under my webserver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 4.2 requires PHP 5.4+, make sure you have that.

If you updated from an earlier version of Laravel and on PHP 5.4+, remove `public_html/bootstrap/compiled.php` and it should work again.

If you can't use 5.4+, use Laravel 4.1 instead of 4.2, so in your `composer.json` you want `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*",` instead of what you have now.